# ember 2.5 trying to query for records using guide

Tags: ember.js

New to ember. Using 2.5.

I've got a list of records, and I want to implement a text search. I have to implement infinite scroll as well, so I guess 'search'ing  is more appropriate than 'filter'ing, since eventually I won't have all records returned.

1] 
I'm following the 'Querying for Multiple Records' guide here
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/finding-records/

So I'm trying to use this format:

```
this.store.query('person', { filter: { name: 'Peter' } }).then(function(peter) {
  console.log(peter);
});
```

This makes a GET, which I can see returns all records, and then spits out a CLASS object:

```
Class {query: Object, store: Class, manager: Class, isLoaded: true, meta: EmptyObject…}
```

I don't really know what kind of thing 'peter' is. I do not see any records listed in it. (Yes, my data does have a Peter in it.)

2]
To see what it's supposed to be doing, I've started a twiddle, here:
https://ember-twiddle.com/f35bb4b593394d955460a83a10f092a4?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

This twiddle did not have a model in it so I added one. But its choking on the GET so obviously this is not the way to implement searches in a twiddle.

Not sure how to get this up and running.

Comment: Hi Dave, are you having difficulty with the request when it's returned in your app, or dynamically changing the filter field ?

Comment: Hi Dave, I think there's a slight misunderstanding afoot. `store.query` won't actually do any filtering, it just makes a query request to your API, passing along the params as query params, and then returns a RecordArray, which is the "peter" object you are seeing. If you do `console.log(peter.content);` you should see the array, or if you expand the object in the console.

Comment: You're right; I must be misunderstanding. I certainly get back an array - all my objects, unfiltered. What use is that?

Comment: @TameBadger: I guess my problem is that there seem to be no examples of how to do this in ember. If I query for records with a param, and get back everything, what am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: A little birdy has suggested that I need to implement "server-side filtering" in Mirage. I have searched online and in the docs and find no such thing.